# c# MailKit Imap Gmail Connection Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mailkit

I have an asp.net web application, and I want to add a button that calls a helper method that will connect to gmail, find a specific message by messageID, and move it (deleted message) back to the inbox. I installed MailKit, and I've looked through so many different examples and trouble-shooting articles on how to connect to imap.gmail.com through a proxy. I am using my company's proxy, and then reading in my gmail username and password from a file. I know the username and password are correct, because I wrote them to the immediate window in Visual Studio Code to see them for testing. However, every time I run the code, click the button and watch the immediate window, it just eventually times out. I just can't seem to get it to connect, and I haven't found any articles that provided a working answer.

I have tried smtp and imap to try to make a connection. Nothing is working. This is my current connection code in the helper method:

```
using (var client = new ImapClient())
{
    client.ProxyClient = new Socks5Client("company proxy address", 80);
    client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
    client.Authenticate(username, password);
    Trace.WriteLine("got here at least");
    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

I installed the MailKit Package. I tried different methods and port numbers: imap port 993 and smtp ports 465 and 587.

For reference, I use the same proxy to connect to gmail in python, and it has no issue. I have not tried to do this with c# before.

Here's the stack trace:

```
[TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.]
   MailKit.Net.Proxy.ProxyClient.Connect(String host, Int32 port, Int32 timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\src\MailKit\MailKit\Net\Proxy\ProxyClient.cs:383
   MailKit.MailService.ConnectNetwork(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\src\MailKit\MailKit\MailService.cs:606
   MailKit.Net.Imap.<ConnectAsync>d__108.MoveNext() in D:\src\MailKit\MailKit\Net\Imap\ImapClient.cs:1440
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   xxxx.Controllers.HomeController.GmailStatusHelper() in C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\Controllers\HomeController.cs:80
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +87
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +77
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +80
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +396
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +651
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +220
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +134
```

At this point I don't know if it is a syntax issue or something else I need to add to make the connection. I think MailKit will work if I get the code right, but if there is a better suggestion to connect with a proxy, I will try. Thank you

Comment: You may be hitting this issue: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/1603

Answer (score 0):

You *may* be hitting this issue: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/1603

I haven't made a new release with that fix (yet), but plan on making a new release by the end of the month. In the meantime, you can try grabbing the latest MailKit nuget from https://www.myget.org/feed/mimekit/package/nuget/MailKit to see if that fixes the issue for you.